# Chaostoolkit istio extension hangs when playing experiment

Tags: testing, istio, chaos

I'm trying to use the chaos toolkit istio extension, my problem is as follows:
I have a experiment.json file which contains a single probe to retrieve a virtual service.  The file looks similar to the following:

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "title": "test",
    "description": "N/A",
    "tags": []
    "secrets": {
        "istio": {
            "KUBERNETES_CONTEXT": {
                "type": "env",
                "key": "KUBERNETES_CONTEXT"
            }
        }
    },
    "method": [
        {
          "type": "probe",
          "name": get_virtual_service:,
          "provider": {
              "type": "python",
              "module": "chaosistio.fault.probes",
              "func": "get_virtual_service",
              "arguments": {
                "virtual_service_name": "test"
                "ns": "test-ns"
              }  
          }
      }
}
```

I have set KUBERNETES_CONTEXT and http/https proxy as env vars. My authorisation is using `$HOME/.kube/config`.

When playing the experiment it validates the file fine and tries to perform the action but becomes stuck and just hangs until it times out.

The error I see in the logs is a HTTPSConnectionPool error (failed to establish a new connection, operation timed out).

Am I missing any settings? All help appreciated.

Comment: There is a space before test `"virtual_service_name": " test"`

Comment: Thanks, this must have occurred as I typed it out for this question (as I couldn’t copy it across)